# How to dynamically use Calculated Properties with Select-Object?

Tags: powershell

I have a function that is meant to take one or more properties from a object, use it as the bases for a new object, while also adding a new property to this new object.

The following is just an example:

```
Function Test{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Array]$Property
    )
    $ObjArgs = @{Property = $Property} 
    Get-ChildItem | Select-Object @ObjArgs,@{Name="AllCapsName";Expression={($_.basename).ToUpper()}}
}
```

I thought using the splatting operator (`@ObjArgs`) would be enough, since `$Property` is already an array

```
Test -Property Mode, Name
```

but the above does not seem to work, I only get `Mode` and `Name` but I do not get the `AllCapsName` property:

```
Mode     Name
-----    -----------
da---     file1
da---     file2
da---     file3
```

I am expecting to get something like this:

```
Mode     Name            AllCapsName
-----    -----------    -----------
da---     file1         FILE1
da---     file2         FILE2
da---     file3         FILE3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove the comma between the splatted variable expression and the hashtable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are wanting, I think this does the job:

```
Function Test{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Array]$Property
    )
    $Property += @{Name="AllCapsName";Expression={($_.basename).ToUpper()}}
    Get-ChildItem | Select-Object $Property
}
Test -Property Mode, Name
```

The code simply expands the input array $Propery by one element, the element needed to define a custom property, and then passes that array to Select-Object.

Also, the 2 commands in the function can be combined, but for some reason it requires wrapping the `+` operation in parentheses.

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object ($Property + @{Name="AllCapsName";Expression={($_.basename).ToUpper()}})
```

Comment: Nice. Passing _expressions_ - such as a `+` operation - as _command arguments_ always requires enclosure in `(...)`